# Provide Calendar Interface for Outlook with ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, calendar

I am developing an MVC5 ASP.Net C# web system that has a series of calendars. Users can access multiple calendars and be associated with multiple events on said calendars.

I would like to expose this data to Outlook (e.g. 2016).

I assume I would have to do this by creating some sort of API.

When a user logs into the web system I would like to provide them with a link ( or URL if it can't be directly clicked to integrate with Outlook) which sets up Outlook on their machine to interact with the API.

I would like Outlook to automatically sync with this calendar without user interaction.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Outlook supports iCalendar (.ics format) natively - if you can provide a feed URL from your application (i.e. some code which builds output in ICS format dynamically with the latest data when a request for that URL is made) for that then the user can click the link and Outlook will subscribe to the calendar automatically. From memory I think there's a C# library around which will create ICS formatted output from whatever source data you give it.

Comment: Alternatively, if this is a corporate project, you could use Exchange Web Services to put data into the users' calendars (or a shared calendar) from the server side, instead of each individual installed copy of Outlook having to be subscribed to a calendar URL.

Comment: Thanks ADyson,the former seems to be exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, it is possible. Optimal and final solution heavily depends on your infrastructure.

**Exchange server**

For this mail server there's plenty of documentation and it is IMO the easiest way. It has built in sync and calendar support. [API documentation is pretty good for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668.aspx) also [for calendars.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations)

**Other email server**

This is the trickiest part and needs more research what is possible and what is not.

First you need to do some deep research about what will be your infrastructure. Then move on to 'customizing' it with some C# app. Good thing is that you at least have chosen the coding-part.